Wrong thumbnail on edited Google Photos pics
When I edit photos using Google Photos, the edited pics are stored in a folder DCIM/PhotosEditor. But the thumbnails for these pics that are displayed in other apps, such as Instagram and X-Plore and Files, show the old, unmodified versions. The new edited versions are displayed when I click on such a wrong thumbnail, but not before.
I have a Samsung Galaxy S10e with Android 12. I have searched how to clear the thumbnail cache, but the instructions usually refer to a .thumbnails folder, which doesn't seem to exist on my system (showing hidden files is enabled of course.)
How can I fix the thumbnails of my edited photos?
